# Assigning ID to object (just one) with javascript

Tags: javascript, element, tagname

For some reason, the code below doesn't work. I need it to assign an ID to **one** object. What am I doing wrong below?

```
  var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").setAttribute("id","iframe");
```

I have a jQuery libary installed, if it should be of any use.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns a NodeList ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList ). It's an Array-like object, which contains references to DOM objects. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery you can make this much simpler:

```
$('iframe').attr('id', 'iframe'); // or:
$('iframe').prop('id', 'iframe');
```

This affects **all** `<iframe>` elements on the page and thus you better have only one. Duplicate IDs are serious business. They break stuff and you really need to avoid them. You could chain in `.first()` or use the `iframe:first` selector to make sure you only target the first element.

---

Here's the jQuery-less solution, also just for the first `<iframe>`:

```
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
frame.id = 'iframe';
```

Line 1: You actually want the (first) `iframe` element in `frame`.
Line 2: The ID is available as a *property* so you can use `.id` instead of `setAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it would return an array, and this solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're targeting the first iframe found:

```
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
frame.setAttribute("id","iframe");
```

The reason you need the `[0]` index is that `getElementsByTagName` will return a collection of all elements with that tag name, even if there is only one.

And, as ThiefMaster said, you could also use `frame.id = "iframe";` instead of `setAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 <script>
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].id="iframe1";  
 alert(document.getElementById("iframe1").name);
 </script>
```